# arreglo de estructuras dentro de una funcion

Tags: funciones, estructuras

tengo este codigo de ejemplo que arme de que pasaria llamo a un arreglo de estructuras en una funcion separada del main, estoy aprendiendo onda prueba y error y me surgió esta duda, y me surgio un error, la funcion no detecta la estructura del main y quisiera saber por que, si me lo pueden corregir por favor, e buscado por la web y no e encontrado nada similar asi que ayudarian a muchas personas que quiza se crucen con este mismo obstáculo.

primeramente el codigo en C metido en un solo archivo funciona perfectamente y no tira niun tipo de error;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct personas
{
char nombre[20];
int edad;
float salario;
}datos[5];
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void carga()
{
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
 {  
  printf("ingresar nombre\n");
  gets(datos[i].nombre);
  printf("\ningresar edad\n");
  scanf("%i",&datos[i].edad);
  printf("\ningresar salario\n");
  scanf("%f",&datos[i].salario);
  fflush(stdin);
 }
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main() 

{
carga();
for(int c=0;c<5;c++)
 {  
  printf("\nnombre %i es: ",c); puts(datos[c].nombre);printf("\n");
  printf("\n edad %i es: %i\n",c,datos[c].edad);
  printf("\nsalario %i es: %2.f\n ",c,datos[c].salario);
  fflush(stdin);
 }
system ("pause");   

return 0;
}
```

ahora bien, el problema es cuando trato de separarlos de esta manera

primer archivo

archivo main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "datos.c"
struct personas
{
char nombre[20];
int edad;
float salario;
}datos[5];
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void carga();
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main() 
{
carga();// funcion cargar datos
for(int c=0;c<5;c++)
 {  
  printf("\nnombre %i es: ",c); puts(datos[c].nombre);printf("\n");
  printf("\n edad %i es: %i\n",c,datos[c].edad);
  printf("\nsalario %i es: %2.f\n ",c,datos[c].salario);
  fflush(stdin);
 }
system ("pause");   

return 0;
}
```

en el siguiente archivo me marca el error justo cuando debe guardar un dato en la estructura del main

10  7 [Error] 'datos' undeclared (first use in this function)

segundo archivo

datos.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void carga()
{
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
 {  
  printf("ingresar nombre\n");
  gets(datos[i].nombre);//justo aqui me marca un error
  printf("\ningresar edad\n");
  scanf("%i",&datos[i].edad);
  printf("\ningresar salario\n");
  scanf("%f",&datos[i].salario);
  fflush(stdin);
 }
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Primero estás cargando `datos.c` y hasta después defines la estructura, es decir, intentas usar la variable antes de definirla. Mueve ese bloque de `main.c` a `datos.c` y debería funcionar:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "datos.c"
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void carga();
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main() 
{
carga();// funcion cargar datos
for(int c=0;c<5;c++)
 {  
  printf("\nnombre %i es: ",c); puts(datos[c].nombre);printf("\n");
  printf("\n edad %i es: %i\n",c,datos[c].edad);
  printf("\nsalario %i es: %2.f\n ",c,datos[c].salario);
  fflush(stdin);
 }
system ("pause");   

return 0;
}
```

datos.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct personas
{
char nombre[20];
int edad;
float salario;
}datos[5];

void carga()
{
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
 {  
  printf("ingresar nombre\n");
  gets(datos[i].nombre);//justo aqui me marca un error
  printf("\ningresar edad\n");
  scanf("%i",&datos[i].edad);
  printf("\ningresar salario\n");
  scanf("%f",&datos[i].salario);
  fflush(stdin);
 }
}
```

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, gracias xdd no cai en eso, que se ejecuta bloque por bloque, me re abriste la mente, muchas gracias de verdad